# Changing Text Link Into A Button

Tags: php, html

I am looking to change a text link into a Bootstrap button, I know how to make a bootstrap button but my problem is I don't know how to edit the code below so it works properly with the button.

```
<li{if $menu == 'videos'} class="active"{/if}><a href="{$relative}/videos">{translate c='menu.videos'}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Page Title</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
            $menu = "videos";   
            $someVariable = "path";
            $relative = $someVariable."/s_path/videos" 
        ?>

        <ul>
            <li class="<?php echo $menu == 'videos' ? 'active' : '' ?>"> 
                <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button"  href="<?php echo $relative ?>">your link name</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using btn class on anchor tag like this.

```
<li{if $menu == 'videos'} class="active"{/if}><a class="btn" role="button" href="{$relative}/videos">{translate c='menu.videos'}</a></li>
```

Add other classes liike btn-success, or btn-sm and so many more classes see bootstrap button details [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/)